# What XDG environment variables should be set at boot?

Tags: environment-variables, display-manager, xdg

Recently I got rid of my display manager and that caused [Plank](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Plank) to not run, complaining that it could only work for X sessions. I was running an X session. Upon a bit of digging, I realised that my `XDG_SESSION_TYPE` was no longer getting set to `x11`. I added `export XDG_SESSION_TYPE="x11"` to `.xsessionrc` and that made Plank run at boot again.

Morel of the story, my display manager was setting some XDG variables and the session type was one of them. I have no idea what other ones it may have been setting. Is there a command I could call that automatically sets all the required XDG environment variables or am I now responsible to set them myself like in case of the session type. Which XDG variables should be set? Which ones are a good idea to have set? `env | grep XDG` only shows the following,

```
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=MATE
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_VTNR=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=1
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```